# C++ - outputting result into xlsx (spreadsheet) rather than CSV

Tags: c++, excel, csv

I have a program that reads and copies text from "in.txt" file, and output the result in "out.csv".

when I try to output the result to "out.xlsx", it creates the file but the file does not open. It's saying the spreadsheet is corrupted. How do I write it so that it outputs the result in spreadsheet?

My "in.text" file contains only one line of String which is a name of a person e.g. Ben.

Here is my program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char inputFilename[] = "C:\\ABC\\ZXY\\in.txt";
    char outputFilename[] = "out.csv";    //change this to "out.xlsx"
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    char username;  


    inFile.open(inputFilename, ios::in);
    if (!inFile) {
        cerr << "Can't open input file " << inputFilename << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    outFile.open(outputFilename, ios::out);
    if (!outFile) {
        cerr << "Can't open output file " << outputFilename << endl;
        exit(1);
    }


    while (inFile >> username) {
        outFile << username++ << endl;
    }


    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An xlsx file is a fairly complex beast--quite different from a CSV file. It's (probably) possible, at least in theory, to create one on your own based on the [ECMA standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm), but it's a very large standard--volume 1 alone is over 5000 pages, and that's only the first of four volumes. Worse, although I haven't tried to ascertain whether it applies to the current edition of the standard, there have been complaints that despite its size, the standard is still incomplete.

The available choices are really:

1. create a CSV file and be done with it
2. use some external library to create the xlsx file
3. dedicate quite a while to creating an xlsx file on your own

When I say "quite a while", I mean probably a minimum of a few weeks, and that's assuming you want to produce something that's still basically equivalent to a csv file--i.e., something that contains only data--and assumes you'll still use an external library for some parts.

I should probably add one more point: an xlsx file is really a zip file. The simplest route to creating a simple one is probably to rename an existing .xlsx file to .zip, then look at (and imitate) its contents.

Comment: Do note that Excel *will* actually open plain text files with the extension `.xls`. I’ve forgotten whether it recognises TSV and/or CSV but at least one of them worked. Of course it’s *terrible* to save those files as `.xls` but biologists do that … :-[

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I'm not sure exactly why, but somehow that scares me a bit.

Comment: There are lots of scary stories involving Excel and biologists … For example, did you know that there’s a gene called “OCT4”? Well, Excel silently changes that to “Oct-04”. And yes, [that has negatively impacted actual research results.](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/gene-name-errors-and-excel-lessons-not-learned/)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I've run into a few things like that with Excel. Worse, it actually changes its internal representation, so in a fair number of cases it's essentially impossible to recover the original data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using an existing library, such as [SimpleXlsxWriter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplexlsx/)

Comment: thanks I wonder if is there any c++ code that show how to use SimpleXlsxWriter to create a spreadhseet